# Angular 9 Ngif giving wrong output because of delayed API response

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I apologise if this isn't well crafted. I'm new here. So I have put together my first SPA and deployed, however the use of Ngif is giving wrong output because of delayed response from the third party API. I am making use of the 'haveibeenpwned' API to retrieve info on specific data breaches. The issue is that because of the delay if the breach does exist it is still displaying 'No breach found!' first before actually displaying the appropriate breach information. I'm using the Ngif to check if the response array is empty and obviously because of the delayed response it will display there is no breach found because the output array is empty at first.

Can I catch it another way without using an Ngif on the view template? So my code is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="breachData.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let item of breachData; let i = index">
    <img src="{{item.LogoPath}}" alt="{{item.Name}}" class="small-logo mb-2">
    <p><strong>Breach Name:</strong> {{item.Name}}</p>
    <p><strong>Date of breach:</strong> {{item.BreachDate | date : "dd/MM/y"}}</p>
    <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
    <p [innerHTML]="item.Description"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!breachData.length">
  <p>No breach found!</p>
</div>
```

I was using Angular 9 when this was produced and I lost part of the code so apologies if that doesn't seem quite right but basically I used an ngIf and ngElse. Is it possible to catch it before output in the view? Like say in the breachcomponent.component.ts ? As I do use the following:

```
this.breachData.push(data);
```

Here is the code for the breachcomponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HibpService} from "../hibp.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breachcomponent',
  templateUrl: './breachcomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breachcomponent.component.css']
})
export class BreachcomponentComponent implements OnInit {
  breach;
  public breachData = [];

  constructor(private hibpService: HibpService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.hibpService.showBreachInfo(params.get('breachName')).subscribe((data) => {
        this.breachData.push(data);
        console.log(this.breachData);
      });
    })
  }

}
```

Sorry if a lot of this is vague. I'm very new to Angular and it was my first app.

Any help appreciated. Please don't mark this down as not well received as I am a beginner.

Comment: could you post your component class code?

Comment: I've read everything on the formatting here but for some reason I cannot get it right so not sure the code would make sense. The two spaces at the end of each line does not cause a line break so my code looks all jumbled up. I've heard about and read a little about using a resolver which would allow the route if the array does have length to it. Is there any way you could provide an example of how I could do this please? The info I've read doesn't state how to actually create a resolver or where to put it.

Comment: Also it won't let me put my code into a comment due to it being over the character length allowed in any one comment on here.

Comment: Hi Dan, you could edit your post and add the code there, instead of in the comment

Comment: @deerawan Hi, I've included the breachcomponent.component.ts code so hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another property called `loaded` and set it to true after data is loaded

```
this.breachData.push(data);
this.loading = true;
```

Your ngIf would look like

```
<div *ngIf="loading && breachData.length">
```

Comment: I've seen something similar to that but how would that work? So yeah I could say if ` this.loading = true;` then display something like an animated spinner but how would the app know when the data has finally loaded? This is kinda confusing me a tad. Please elaborate further.

Comment: Sorry I realised it didn't format my code `this.loading = true;`

Comment: Here is the full code for my breachcomponent.component.html file:  
`<div *ngIf="breachData.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let item of breachData; let i = index">
    <img src="{{item.LogoPath}}" alt="{{item.Name}}" class="small-logo mb-2">
    <p><strong>Breach Name:</strong> {{item.Name}}</p>
    <p><strong>Date of breach:</strong> {{item.BreachDate | date : "dd/MM/y"}}</p>
    <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
    <p [innerHTML]="item.Description"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!breachData.length">
  <p>No breach found!</p>
</div>`

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't formatting correctly. I've looked at the documentation and it says two spaces at the end of a line to cause a line break but that isn't working! Getting tad frustrated with this system.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this please? I've been trying to read up on various methods but as of right now I really don't know which way to go.